# Why doesn't LocateRegistry.getRegistry() fail if I specify the wrong port number?

Tags: java, rmi, distributed, distributed-computing

I'm trying to distribute a simple room booking system that I implemented, I tried researching and this is what I came up with.. but When I run them and enter different port numbers the client still runs..shouldn't it only run if the port number matches the one I entered for Server? what did I do wrong?

For Client :

```
 public static void main (String[] args)
{
Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);

int portNum = 1099;//default port 
try {
          System.out.print("Enter the port number");
          portNum= s.nextInt();

            Registry reg= LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", portNum);

        System.out.println("Connected to RMI server");
```

For Server:

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {
int portNum = 1099;
 try {

     Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
 HotelServer  server  = new HotelServer ();
 //register it with the local naming registry
   try
      {

       System.out.print("Enter The Port Number");
       portNum= s.nextInt();
          Registry reg= LocateRegistry.createRegistry(portNum);
          reg.bind("localhost", server);
          System.out.println("Server started");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just getting a result from `LocateRegistry.getRegistry()` doesn't indicate that you're connected to anything. It doesn't perform any network operations. It just constructs a stub. If the port number isn't correct, you won't find out until you try to use it.

Comment: I don't understand, what would I have to change now?

Comment: I've answered that. 'Try to use it.' Try to use the Registry stub you acquired, i.e. do the lookup; then try to call the remote object. Only then can you be sure that you have a valid setup. Remove the misleading message that says you're connected. There is no such thing as an RMI connection, so don't tell the user he's connected when he isn't.

Comment: I get this error.. java.rmi.UnknownHostException: Unknown host: l; nested exception is: 
 java.net.UnknownHostException: l

Comment: no sorry, that was because I misspelled "localhost".. Now i get this error java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to HotelServer.. what caused it?

Comment: You're trying to cast the stub to the implementation class. It isn't the implementation class, it is a stub implementing the same remote interface(s). So cast it to the remote interface.